# discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionNotFound: Extension 'cogs.mod' could not be loaded Error

Tags: discord.py

Can someone help me fix my discord bot please made in 2021 now it need an up date i keep geting an error

Old Code

```
cogs_dir = "cogs"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for extension in [f.replace('.py', '') for f in listdir(cogs_dir) if isfile(join(cogs_dir, f))]:
        try:
            bot.load_extension(cogs_dir + "." + extension)
        except (discord.ClientException, ModuleNotFoundError):
            print(f'Failed to load extension {extension}.')
```

My Error

```
main.py:57: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited
  bot.load_extension(cogs_dir + "." + extension)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

How can i fix this

Answer (score 0):

Your error says

> coroutine was never awaited

and indeed you're never awaiting `load_extension`, which is now a coroutine, as the error suggests.

The migration guide in the docs tells you how to... migrate...: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous

A migration guide is always the first place to look if you want to keep old code functional.

Comment: Would you be able to help and gide me with this

Comment: The docs page I linked has comments that tell you what to change. That should suffice. If you have any questions feel free to ask, but I'm not gonna do it for you.

Comment: im not good with it someone made me it and im trying to update i can give discord if that helps

Comment: I don't see how giving your discord would help. StackOverflow is not a code writing service where you can ask people to fix your code, you should learn & at least try to do it yourself first. The migration guide literally tells you what to do. As I said: if you've got questions then you can ask them, but I'm not gonna do it for you.